# Postbuild Event in .vcxproj

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I am trying to make a postbuild event reference to a `.props` file in a `.vcxproj`

What elements fits between the `PostBuildEvent` Tag?

Although it's not valid i am looking for something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <PostBuildEvent>  
  <ProjectReference Include="default.props">
  </ProjectReference>
 </PostBuildEvent>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can include a .props file inside an event. Include the props file you want outside the ItemGroup. [For example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/14/a-guide-to-vcxproj-and-props-file-structure.aspx):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' >
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\default.props" />
</Project>
```

In your props file, you can have your PostBuildEvent defined:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <PostBuildEvent>  
  <Command>copy $(ProjectDir)$(Configuration)\$(TargetFileName) $(ProjectDir)$(Configuration)\copyOfMyproject.exe</Command>
  <Message>Making a copy of myproject.exe</Message>
 </PostBuildEvent>
</ItemGroup>
```

The above example is from [How to: Use Build Events in MSBuild Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293582.aspx). Please note that you may need to set the item PostBuildEventUseInBuild in the PropertyGroup in your props file.